# How can I return errors from component first before applying global http interceptor to handle error?

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, angular-httpclient

Currently, I am using http interceptor to handle all errors globally. E.g. if a http error returns as 404, it displays a snackbar that says "404: Page not found" by the http interceptor. This is great for handling all errors generally but at times, for specific service calls, I know the issue is because an item is not found in a store and the server returns 404. Instead of "page not found", I want it to return "product is not in store" for only that call. The rest of the 404 errors can be handled generically.

However, I'm not sure how to do this as Http interceptor comes first before the error handling in my service/component.

Here's my http interceptor at the moment:

```
@Injectable()
export class RequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    public errorHandler: ErrorHandler,
  ) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {}, (err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        this.errorHandler.handleError(err);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Here's my error handler:

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorHandler {

  constructor(
    public snackbar: MatSnackBar, private router: Router
  ) {}

  public handleError(err: any) {

    if (err.status === 400) {
        this.snackbar.open('400: There was a bad request', 'close');
    } else if (err.status === 401) {
        this.snackbar.open('401: Unauthorized', 'close');
    } else if (err.status === 403) {
        this.snackbar.open('403: Forbidden', 'close');
    } else if (err.status === 404) {
        this.snackbar.open('404: Page not found', 'close');
    } else if (err.status === 500) {
        this.router.navigate(['/error']);
    } else {
        this.snackbar.open(err.message, 'close');
    }
  }
}
```

And e.g. here's my service call that I want the error for this to appear first:

```
getProductByNumber(storeId: number, productNum: number): Observable<any> {
   this.products = this.baseUrl + '/products/' + storeId + '/' + productNum;
   return this.http.get<IProduct>(this.products).catch(this.errorHandler);
  }
```

where

```
errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.status === 404) {
      this.openSnackBar('Product is not found in store');
      return Observable.throw(error.message || 'Server Error');
    } else {
      return Observable.throw(error.message || 'Server Error');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your error passed to the error handler has the URL on it. Did you try to use that to conditionally display another message when that type of resource gets the 404?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel no? Can you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: `HttpErrorResponse` has a property `url` that you can use to determine if the request was for one of these special routes (probably using a regular expression). You can just modify your `ErrorHandler` class to do the extra work to determine if the 404 was for one of these special requests and display the different toast there.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel oh I see, that's a very interesting approach. I like the idea but it will be a bit complicated to come up with the regex. Let me see if I can do a simple regex for at least one of the calls.

Comment: For the example service above it would be something like `/\/products\/\d+\/\d+$/`

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel thanks. I might need that for the more complicated urls but I was just thinking if I do a  string compare for '/api/products/' && err.status === 400, I will get a match for the error. So I don't need to do the regex but I am worried about more complicated api calls that have query params where this might be helpful. Thanks a lot for your input!